# How to programmatically change value of Mat-Select without FormControl

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to programmatically change the value of a mat-select element. I have already seen a number of answers around the internet suggesting to use the FormControl method to change the value, however I have a limitation that I am coding within a 3rd party product, and it does not have access to FormControl.

Does anyone have any possible recommendations for how I can approach this?

All help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You can us ngModel to do so as you are binding it.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried ngModel before making this post, it also doesn't work. Do you know if there's any way to drill into the mat-select object itself and set the selected value? I haven't been able to find any documentation that details how I might do this.

Comment: If you are using mat-select as you have mentioned above then it should work for sure. However you also mentioned you are using 3rd party control, please share the code for the same.

Comment: I have looked into the problem more, and it turns out the issue was related to the 3rd party software. The 3rd party software is ThingsBoard. In order to make use of the [(ngModel)] method, I needed to add the value to the context eg self.ctx.$scope.selected.

Comment: Are you using Angularjs or angular? Angular does not have something called as $scope.

Comment: As I said, this is the context created by the third party software, this isn't purely Angular, it uses Angular elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was related to ThingsBoard and how it handles putting values into the context. Angular will immediately use a value declared in the ts, in the html. ThingsBoard needs the value to be added manually to the context eg
`self.ctx.$scope.[variable]`

Answer (score -1):

you can change the value of `selected` property in ts and as it is a two way binding it should reflect the change in mat-select